# How to keep xsd keyref confined to a specific element?

Tags: xml, xsd

The W3C online validator says the XML below is valid based on the schema.  But I thought the way the schema was constructed (specifically with key/keyref constraints) that it would be invalid.

**Schema:**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://testSchema"
           xmlns="http://testSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:complexType name="defFooType">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="defBarType">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="useFooType">
    <xs:attribute name="use" type="xs:IDREF" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="testType">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="defFoo" type="defFooType"/>
      <xs:element name="defBar" type="defBarType"/>
      <xs:element name="useFoo" type="useFooType"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="test" type="testType">
    <xs:key name="FOOKEY">
      <xs:selector xpath="./defFoo"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:keyref name="FOOKEYREF" refer="FOOKEY">
      <xs:selector xpath="./useFoo"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@use"/>
    </xs:keyref>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

**Test XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<test xmlns="http://testSchema">
  <defFoo name="foo1"/>
  <defBar name="bar1"/>
  <useFoo use="bar1"/>
</test>
```

I'm trying to restrict `<useFoo>` elements' `use` attribute to refer only to the `name` attribute of `<defFoo>` elements. I don't understand why `<useFoo use="bar1"/>` doesn't cause validation to fail. Have I set up the key/keyref wrong?  Is there something else I need to add?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer, so rather than delete the question I thought I'd post it in case someone else runs into this.

It seems that the schema being defined needs a target namespace for the XPATH in the `xs:selector` statement to find what I wanted it to find.  Apparently, XPATH expressions won't do what I was expecting when the elements are in the default namespace.

Here is the reference that gave me the clue:

> "Special consideration must be given to namespaces when defining
>   identity constraints. Qualified element-type names and attribute names
>   used in the XPath expressions must be prefixed in order to be
>   legal.....Note that the target namespace is mapped to a prefix, rather
>   than being the default namespace. This is because XPath expressions
>   are not affected by default namespace declarations. Unqualified names
>   in XPath expressions are always assumed to be 
>   in no namespace."
>
> *Walmsley, Priscilla (2001-12-07). Definitive XML Schema (Charles F.
>   Goldfarb Definitive XML Series) (Kindle Locations 6982-6984). Pearson
>   Education.*

While this might not be talking about the precise issue I was dealing with, I was able to resolve my issue by using a non-default namespace for my schema.

So this resulting schema gets the validation error I was expecting:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://testSchema"
           xmlns:mine="http://testSchema"
           elementFormDefault="qualified"
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified">

  <xs:complexType name="defFooType">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="defBarType">
    <xs:attribute name="name" type="xs:ID" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="useFooType">
    <xs:attribute name="use" type="xs:IDREF" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="testType">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="defFoo" type="mine:defFooType"/>
      <xs:element name="defBar" type="mine:defBarType"/>
      <xs:element name="useFoo" type="mine:useFooType"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="test" type="mine:testType">
    <xs:key name="FOOKEY">
      <xs:selector xpath="./mine:defFoo"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@name"/>
    </xs:key>
    <xs:keyref name="FOOKEYREF" refer="mine:FOOKEY">
      <xs:selector xpath="./mine:useFoo"/>
      <xs:field xpath="@use"/>
    </xs:keyref>
  </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```